# how to create a hive UDF for all sessions

Tags: hive

I can create an UDF and configure it for current hive session using `CREATE TEMPORARY FUNCTION`. Is there a way to do this once and make this function available for all future sessions for all users?

Answer (score 3):

For using a UDF, you need 2 steps:

1. Making the UDF jar available for all nodes in the cluster. This is typically done by adding it to the distributed cache of the cluster by a command like `ADD JAR my_jar.jar`
2. Registering your UDF so that it can be recognized by Hive. This basically links the name of the UDF (e.g. from_unixtime) with the class of the UDF (org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.udf.FromUnixTime). This is typically done by a command like `CREATE TEMPORARY FUNCTION from_unixtime AS 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.udf.FromUnixTime';`

So, in order for you to make the UDFs available for all users, you have to do the above 2 steps. For #1, you can do something like `export HIVE_AUX_JARS_PATH = <path to the folder>` in hive-env.sh that would make the jars available.

Getting #2 is tricky, the best way would be have support in the Hive metastore to have linking between UDF name and class name. However, that's presently not the case. So, there is no real good way of doing this.

What I would recommend is to use .hiverc file which does both #1 and #2 above. Place it in your home directory or hive bin directory (although a patch is in works to pick it up from hive conf directory as well). The only catch is that it only works when users are accessing hive through CLI. If you are using JDBC, you have to manually source that file at the beginning of your Hive session.

Answer (score 2):

Can you find a .hiverc file in locations like: $HIVE_HOME/bin/.hiverc and $HOME/.hiverc? If you find one then open the file and just add your CREATE TEMPORARY FUNCTION command there. Then every time you start hive this .hiverc file will be loaded and so your UDF will be regiseterd for all sessions of HIVE.

Achyut

Answer (score 0):

Expanding on the above answers:  in order to truly make UDF's available to all users/sessions it is required:

- add the UDF to the hive libs/ directory and/or HIVE_AUX_JARS_PATH
- add the function to the **FunctionRegistry**  class and recompile hive. Yes. not so fun ;)

From the Hive Bible (Programming Hive):

```
Here is an example change to FunctionRegistry where the new nvl() function is added
to Hive’s list of built-in functions:
...
registerUDF("parse_url", UDFParseUrl.class, false);
```

Answer (score 0):

One of the answers in [how to add a permanent function in hive?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20043448/how-to-add-a-permanent-function-in-hive) points out that since Hive 13 there is a CREATE FUNCTION feature available for permanent functions as described at https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+DDL#LanguageManualDDL-PermanentFunctions.

Answer (score 0):

From hive 0.13 onwards UDFs can be stored in metastore and can be referenced in a query

```
CREATE FUNCTION [db_name.]function_name AS class_name
  [USING JAR|FILE|ARCHIVE 'file_uri' [, JAR|FILE|ARCHIVE 'file_uri'] ];
```

Example :

```
CREATE FUNCTION woy AS 'com.udf.hive.WOYUDF' USING JAR 'hdfs:///user/root/udfhive-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar';
```