# Adding hive jars permanently

Tags: hadoop, hive

Is there any way I can add hive jars permanently instead of adding at session level in hive shell?

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Do you mean JARs for custom UDFs?

Comment: any jar required by query ..like csv-serde jar for loading csv files into table

Answer (score 9):

In the hiveserver2 host, create a location something like /var/lib/hive and add all the necessary jars inside that folder. Edit the *hive-site.xml* and mention all these jars in the property *hive.aux.jars.path*

Eg:

`ADD JAR /home/amal/hive/amaludf.jar
ADD JAR /home/amal/hive/amaludf2.jar`

Instead of using the above commands in each session, you can define it for all sessions.

Create a location for storing these jars in the hiveserver host.

```
mkdir /var/lib/hive
```

Add all these jars to that directory

Set the property in *hive-site.xml*

```
<property>
  <name>hive.aux.jars.path</name>
  <value>/var/lib/hive</value>
</property>
```

Restart the hiveserver2 after doing this modification.

Instead of creating a directory and putting all the jars, you can specify paths of individual jars also. The only condition is that all these jars should be present in the hiveserver host.

Eg:

```
<property>
  <name>hive.aux.jars.path </name>
  <value>file:///home/amal/hive/udf1.jar,file:///usr/lib/hive/lib/hive-hbase-handler.jar</value>
</property>
```

Answer (score 0):

You will have to put the jar in the **lib** folder of hadoop or hive in **all** your nodes.

Answer (score 0):

these can be done by two steps

> 1. Hive Client should be avalable in all nodes.
> 2. Hive Live location should be defined in hadoop-env.sh CLASSPATH and the same file should be updated in entired Hadoop Clueter.

{hadoop-env.sh should be update with CLASSPATH of hive and other location for  user defined custom jars and common location which available in entire cluster   }

You also need to restart the hive/hadoop to take effect if after changes it dnt work.

Answer (score 0):

create directory named `auxlib` in $HIVE_HOME, put all your jars in this directory and restart the hive server. run `ps -ef | grep hive` this command to list hive processes, search for `hive.aux.jars.path` and you will see that all your jars will be listed against this hiveconf.